Замеры памяти в rust
Есть ли в rust что-то похожее, подойдет абсолютно абсолютно любой аналог такого измерения.
Данный пример на python:
    tracemalloc.start()
    func(source, target)
    curr, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
    tracemalloc.stop()


Посмотри https://docs.rs/dhat/latest/dhat/ , может подойдёт
